# How to prevent a NoCredentialsError when calling the fit method in SageMaker?

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I am a newbie when it comes to Python SageMaker (my background is C#). Currently, I have a problem because the last method call (I mean the fit method) results in a "NoCredentialsError". I do not understand that. The AWS credentials have been set and I do use them to communicate with AWS, for example to communicate with S3. How can I prevent this error?

```
import io
import os
import gzip
import pickle
import urllib.request
import boto3
import sagemaker
import sagemaker.amazon.common as smac

DOWNLOADED_FILENAME = 'C:/Users/Daan/PycharmProjects/downloads/mnist.pkl.gz'
if not os.path.exists(DOWNLOADED_FILENAME):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz", DOWNLOADED_FILENAME)

with gzip.open(DOWNLOADED_FILENAME, 'rb') as f:
    train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
vectors = train_set[0].T
buf = io.BytesIO()
smac.write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(buf, vectors)
buf.seek(0)
key = 'recordio-pb-data'
bucket_name = 'SOMEKINDOFBUCKETNAME'
prefix = 'sagemaker/pca'
path = os.path.join(prefix, 'train', key)
print(path)

session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id='SECRET',aws_secret_access_key='SECRET',region_name='eu-west-1')
client = boto3.client('sagemaker',region_name='eu-west-1',aws_access_key_id='SECRET',aws_secret_access_key='SECRET')
region='eu-west-1'
sagemakerSession= sagemaker.Session(sagemaker_client=client,boto_session=session)
s3_resource=session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
current_bucket = bucket.Object(path)

train_data = 's3://{}/{}/train/{}'.format(bucket_name, prefix, key)
print('uploading training data location: {}'.format(train_data))
current_bucket.upload_fileobj(buf)

output_location = 's3://{}/{}/output'.format('SOMEBUCKETNAME', prefix)
print('training artifacts will be uploaded to: {}'.format(output_location))

region='eu-west-1'

containers = {'us-west-2': 'SOMELOCATION',
              'us-east-1': 'SOMELOCATION',
              'us-east-2': 'SOMELOCATION',
              'eu-west-1': 'SOMELOCATION'}
container = containers[region]

role='AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-SOMEVALUE'
pca = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(container,
                                    role,
                                    train_instance_count=1,
                                    train_instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
                                    output_path=output_location,
                                    sagemaker_session=sagemakerSession)


pca.set_hyperparameters(feature_dim=50000,
                        num_components=10,
                        subtract_mean=True,
                        algorithm_mode='randomized',
                        mini_batch_size=200)

pca.fit(inputs=train_data)

print('END')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you have masked the actual access id and key or this is what you are running.

```
session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id='SECRET',aws_secret_access_key='SECRET',region_name='eu-west-1')
client = boto3.client('sagemaker',region_name='eu-west-1',aws_access_key_id='SECRET',aws_secret_access_key='SECRET')
```

I am hoping you are providing the actual aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key in the above lines of code.

Another way of specifying the same and not hardcoding in the code is to create a credentials file in your profile directory i.e.

in Mac    ~/.aws/

and in Windows `"%UserProfile%\.aws"`

the file is a plain text file with a name "credentials" (without the quotes).
file contains

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

AWS CLI would pick it up from the above location and use it. You can also use non-default profiles and pass on the profile with

```
os.environ["AWS_PROFILE"] = "profile-name"
```

Hope this helps.